# Get global variable dynamically by name string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
//in one script
var someVarName_10 = 20;
</script>
```

I want to get access to this variable from another script by name of variable. With window object its simple, is it possible with local variable?

I mean access this var by code like this:

```
<script>
  const num = 10;
  alert(all_vars['someVar' + 'Name_' + num]);
</script>
```

Comment: Your sample shows a global variable. You want to know if you can access it from a local scope?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by 'local scope'.. Javascript functions are scoped only to functions, not blocks or even files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to access a javascript variable using a string that contains the name of the variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441532/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-javascript-variable-using-a-string-that-contains-the-n)

Comment: Most of these answers relate to the title of the question but don't understand what the body text is asking for. Can you clarify, or ideally, edit the question body to match the title? I'm more than happy to do this on your behalf, but I wanted to ask permission first.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
<script>
//in one script
var someVarName_10 = 20;

alert(window["someVarName_10"]); //alert 20

</script>
```

**Update**: because OP edited the question.

```
<script>
  num=10;
  alert(window['someVar' + 'Name_' + num]); //alert 20
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, i thought that vars are not in window, thanks

Comment: I don't care what OP *actually* wanted. I care about what is in question title and therefore becomes google result in my searches.

Comment: What if the variable is **object**, and I want **inner object**? for example `var a = {name: "ABC"}`. Here `window["a.name"]` will not work. Any workarounds?

Comment: @DeepakChaudhary, `window[a.name]`?

Comment: It says `undefined`, and BTW we need to access the variable by string.
I can thing of making a function `getVariableByKey` and looping by splitting variable by `.`(dot). Is it good way to do so, or go for `eval` ?

Comment: @DeepakChaudhary, may be you want something like lodash's _.get? - https://lodash.com/docs#get

Comment: That would be window["a"].name;

Answer (score 52):

I've noticed that everyone is advising global var creation this will lead to variables leak to global namespace. 
When you dynamically creating classnames or just variables it's easy to keep em local:

```
this['className'] = 123;
```

or

```
this['varName'] = 123;
```

Name-spacing would look like this:

```
vars = {};
vars['varName'] = 123;
vars.varName // 123
```

Comment: This is better than accepted answer. More descriptive about how this feature works in class scopes.

Answer (score 17):

```
<script>
    var someVarName_10 = 20;
    var num = 10;
    alert(eval('someVar' + 'Name_' + num)); //alert 20
</script>
```

Comment: `eval` worked better for me! but use it with caution

Answer (score 1):

This is not my own answer, its [Arthur Araújo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029888/what-are-the-alternatives-to-eval-in-javascript#answer-44103168), but I think its relevent here.

---

Eval alternative:

```
exp = '1 + 1'
x = Function('return ' + exp)()
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

well, for **debugging purpose only**, you could do something like this. I use it during the development of classes, where some variables must remain private (var). this work even in local variable (and global of curse)

```
function MYCLASS(){
    var a=1, b=2, c=3;
    this.public = "variable";
    this.debug = function(sVar){
        return eval(sVar);
    }
}

var myThing = new MYCLASS();
myThing.debug('a') //return 1
myThing.debug('b') //return 2
myThing.debug('c') //return 3
```

Answer (score -9):

If this is what you said:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hello = 'test';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert (hello);
</script>
```

It works because script are finally available to the document and you can access their vars.