# What are the Alternatives to eval in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a little bit of code that looks just like this:

```
function StrippedExample(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8) {
    this.i = [];
    for (var i=1,j=0 ;i<9;i++) {
        var k = eval("i"+i);
        if (k > 0) {
            this.i[j++] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

FireBug profiler claims that second longest function is eval(), taking up to nearly 6% of the run time.

[Everyone says eval is EVIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) (as in bad) and slow (as I have found), but I can't really do anything else - the server simply pulls the data out the database and pushes to the browser.

**What alternatives do I have?** I could do the same as I am doing here on the server but that just shifts the burden higher up the chain. I can't change the database layout since everything hooks into those 8 variables and is a massive undertaking.

Comment: Hopefully this will help show people that you never have to use `eval`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
function StrippedExample(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8) {
    var args = [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8]; // put values in an array
    this.i = [];
    for (var i=0,j=0 ;i<8;i++) { // now i goes from 0-7 also
        var k = args[i]; // get values out
        if (k > 0) {
            this.i[j++] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code can be simplified further, I just made the minimal change to get rid of `eval`. You can get rid of `j`, for example:

```
function StrippedExample(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8) {
    var args = [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8];
    this.i = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        var k = args[i];
        if (k > 0) { this.i.push(k); }
    }
}
```

is equivalent. Or, to use the built-in `arguments` object (to avoid having your parameter list in two places):

```
function StrippedExample(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8) {
    this.i = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var k = arguments[i];
        if (k > 0) { this.i.push(k); }
    }
}
```

Even if you weren't filtering the list, you don't want to do something like `this.i = arguments` because `arguments` is not a real Array; it has a `callee` property that you don't need and is missing some array methods that you might need in `i`. As others have pointed out, if you want to quickly convert the `arguments` object into an array, you can do so with this expression:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
```

You could use that instead of the `var args = [i1, i2 ...` lines above.

Comment: This code is currently incorrect, as it's using 1-indexing while the array is 0-indexed. It's also definitely more complicated than it needs to be, as you could just replace `args` with the built in `arguments` array, and not define it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Brian. I think I fixed it.

Comment: Now you've missed the `if (k > 0)` part from the original.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I think we're OK. What a weird piece of code.

Comment: Another reason to not do `this.i = arguments` is that `arguments` is also *missing* properties you might want in `i`, since it isn't an array.

Comment: A better example would be `this.i = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`.

Comment: @Elijah: that's definitely more concise, but not very readable. Is it even correct? The first argument is supposed to be dropped.

Comment: The first argument isn't supposed to be dropped. Arguments are only supposed be dropped if they are equal to 0.

Comment: I won't use the built-in `arguments` as there are other parameters being passed - this was a stripped down example.  If I knew of the `arguments` keyword(?) then I would of realised it was relevant and then had extra parameters.

Comment: Sorry I got the `(k > 0)` part wrong. Just made a (hopefully) final edit. Glad it was helpful all the same.

Answer (score 14):

Eval alternative:

```
let exp = '1 + 1'
let x = new Function('return ' + exp)()
console.log(x)
```

Comment: +1 For suggesting an alternative to eval(). Unfortunately it is rejected by CSP (default-src 'self') just like eval in Firefox.

Answer (score 8):

You are simply making an array from your function 8 arguments, removing the ones that are less than or equal to zero.

The following code is equivalent, and it will work for any arbitrary number of arguments:

```
function StrippedExample() {
  var args = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] > 0) {
      args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `if (k > 0)` part.

Answer (score 5):

1. Call the function with one argument — an Array
2. Use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Arguments) object

Answer (score 4):

One alternative to to pass an array to your function, instead of individual arguments:

```
StrippedExample([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6])
```

Then your code would be:

```
function StrippedExample(inArray) {
    this.i = [];
    for (var i=0,j=0 ;i<inArray.length;i++) {
        var k = inArray[i];
        if (k > 0) {
            this.i[j++] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

If you really need to pass in separate arguments, you can access them using your [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Arguments) array, which is an object that acts like an array (though it's not really; not all Array methods work on it) that exposes all arguments that have been passed in to your function; they do not even need to be declared in this case, but it's good form to include a comment indicating what sorts of arguments you are expecting for users of your code:

```
function StrippedExample(/*i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8*/) {
    this.i = [];
    for (var i=0,j=0 ;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        var k = arguments[i];
        if (k > 0) {
            this.i[j++] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

If you're guaranteed to only have 8 elements, then you could use `8` in place of `inArray.length` or `arguments.length`; I decided to use the more general version in my examples in case that was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be made to use the `arguments` array that every Javascript function has access to.

It's not that `eval` is **evil** (it's in Lisp, so it must be **good**) it's simply a sign of a hack - you need something to work and you forced it. It screams out to me "The author gave up on good programming design and just found something that worked".

Comment: I'm not au fait with all the ins and outs of Javascript. I can hack around to get things done, but as demonstrated here, it's not always the best way.

Comment: So one of these complicated workaround aren't hacks, but this convenient, one line function is the hack?

Answer (score 1):

```
function StrippedExample() {

    this.i = [];
    for (var i=1,j=0 ;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        var k = arguments[i];
        if (k > 0) {
            this.i[j++] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Short answer:

```
StrippedExample=(...a)=>a.filter(i=>i>0);
```

no need use **eval** for work with arguments at all.

2. Initial code and most proposed solutions doesn't return result by traditional way.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is a fixed amount of variables, you can build an array of them manually and loop through it. But if you have a variable amount of arguments, one way to get the variables passed to the function as an array is:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments.callee.caller.arguments);
```

And your function would look like this:

```
function StrippedExample() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments.callee.caller.arguments);
    for(var i in args) {
        if (args[i] > 0) {
            this.i[j++] = args[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `for..in` to iterate arrays. A simple `for` loop is better.

Answer (score 0):

definitely try this as a drop in replacement.
I was looking for this answer and came to this post.
I read the developer doc and this worked as a direct replacement in my application

```
var func1 = "stringtxt" + object  + "stringtxt";


instead of --->    eval(func1);    --> use -->   Function(func1)();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's the suggested alternative here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 0):

You can also run string expressions with setTimeout. It works the same as the Function object.

```
let a=10;
window.a=100;
window.b=1;
setTimeout("let c=1000;console.log(a,b,c)");//10,1,1000
```