# How to create javascript variable with other variable value in name

Tags: javascript

Hi I need to create a load of variables in a javascript loop so say my loop goes round 5 times starting at 0 by the end of it the following variables should be defined:

```
variable_0
variable_1
variable_2
variable_3
variable_4
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

Comment: What will you be using the variables for?

Comment: Use an object or array for grouping stuff please :X also possible duplicate of [Javascript dynamic variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5117127/995876)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Get local variable dynamicly by name string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/javascript-get-local-variable-dynamicly-by-name-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will create "global" variables by registering them on the `window` object:

```
for (var i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
    window['variable_' + i] = null;
}
```

It's not really nice to do that though =/ a better way is to define an object in which you create dynamic properties.

```
var obj = {}
for (var i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
    obj['variable_' + i] = null;
}

console.log(obj.variable_0); // null
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use an array:

```
var variable = [];
```

If you really want to create 5 variables, you need to choose the scope of them, the easiest is probably `window`, then you can use the sqare bracket syntax:

```
for(var i=0;i<5; i++){
    window["variable_" + i] = 0; // or anything really!
}
```

Now the following variable is available:

```
window.variable_1 = 123
```

Comment: you can use the square bracket syntax on _any_ object.

Comment: @Alnitak - I didnt say you couldn't! I just used `window` as the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create variably *named* variables as part of an `Object`:

```
obj['variable_' + i] = value;
```

There's no equivalent for function scoped variables, although you can of course do:

```
function foo() {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; ... ) {
        obj['variable_' + i] = value;
    }
}
```

You can fake global variables (but shouldn't) by using the `window` global object in place of `obj`, as shown by @Jack.

Of course in most circumstances (and since you're using numbers to differentiate the variables) what you should really do is use an array:

```
var myvar = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    myvar[i] = ...;
}
```