# choose jquery variable to change

Tags: jquery

`#date` is a select tag (dropdown menu).

I already have a variable `date001` and I want to change its value according to new value of dropdown menu.

```
$("#date").change(function() {
    var a = $("#room").html();  // result is `001` - it's ok
    var $("date" + a) = $(this).val(); // doesn't work !
});
```

Comment: This is not a variable, it's a `jQuery` object: `$("date" + a)`

Comment: Also, if you already have a variable, by using `var` you just created another one in this scope.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, what is the correct way? I need to change the value of  `date001` var.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Get local variable dynamicly by name string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/javascript-get-local-variable-dynamicly-by-name-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("date" + a)` is a jQuery selector; it's not doing what you think it's doing.

What's more likely is doing something like this:

```
window['date' + a] = $(this).val();
```

This isn't good practice, so perhaps you should attach your `date001` variable, and others like it, to an object and reference them that way.

```
myObj['date' + a] = $(this).val();
```