# Syntax to build object properties in loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to loop through a list of objects and display one property on a graph on the page but I can't seem to get the right syntax to get this data in a loop.

Without the loop this gives an idea of what I want to do:

```
document.getElementById("v1").innerHTML = zone1.sensor; 
document.getElementById("v2").innerHTML = zone2.sensor;
document.getElementById("v3").innerHTML = zone3.sensor;
```

I can't figure out how to loop through the objects, something like this:

```
for(i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
document.getElementById("v" + i).innerHTML = ("zone" + i + ".sensor");
}
```

Comment: The zones should definitely be an array instead of individual variables, but other than that this is a duplicate of [JavaScript: Get local variable dynamically by name string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/javascript-get-local-variable-dynamically-by-name-string)

Comment: You have the wrong approach. Programming is about abstraction. You shouldn't have `zone1`, `zone2`, and `zone3`, but instead an array of objects: `var zones = []`

Answer (score 4):

While that *can* be done with `eval()` or `new Function ()`, that's just plain wrong. Put your values in an array and access them by index. If you absolutely have to use independent variables, do:

```
var arr = [zone1, zone2, zone3];
```

and then use

```
arr[i].sensor
```

Comment: Agreed, this approach is much better than my own.

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way to avoid the use of `eval`:

```js
var zone1 = new Object;
var zone2 = new Object;
var zone3 = new Object;

zone1.sensor = "sensor1";
zone2.sensor = "sensor2";
zone3.sensor = "sensor3";

var zones = [zone1, zone2, zone3];

for( var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  document.getElementById("v" + i).innerHTML = zones[i - 1]["sensor"];
}
```

```html
<div id="v1"></div>
<div id="v2"></div>
<div id="v3"></div>
```

Hope it helps!