# Attribute value as variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, var, attr

I'm trying to get a dynamic attribute value to be used as a var name
What I have:

```
$(this).html(""+$(this).attr("id")+"");
```

It gives me the value as plain text. What I want is that it uses the attr("id") value as a Var like:

```
$(this).html(""+myVar+"")
```

Final example:

```
<div class="text" id="text1"></div>
<div class="text" id="text2"></div>


var text1 = "hello world"
var text2 = "bye world"
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".text").click(function(){
      $(this).html(""+$(this).attr("id")+"");  
   });
});
```

Basically I want a dynamic way of calling to certain id's and getting their attribute value to be used as the Var name instead of plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on variable namespace and scope, but generally next code should do the job.

```
$(".text").click(function(){
    var varFromAttr = window[$(this).attr("id")];
    $(this).html(varFromAttr);
});
```

Question is almost the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/javascript-get-local-variable-dynamically-by-name-string).

Comment: I didn't know about this window[]; function. And i couldn't make out what was going on in the other questions.

Comment: @IanHogers Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it did thank you.

Comment: @IanHogers You can mark answer as **accepted** if it helped you and give it a **vote up**. Thanks.