# reference javascript variable through concatenation

Tags: javascript

I have few javascript variables:

```
var column1
var column2
var column3
etc...
```

I have a for loop,

```
for (i=1; i<10; i++) {}
```

I would like to loop through and reference these variable inside the for loop. How do I reference each `column` variable individually? I'm looking to do something like this:

```
for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
  columni = i;
}
```

so at the end of this I'll have:

```
column1 = 1
column2 = 2
column3 = 3
```

Comment: you could use `eval`.................. but you're probably better off with @brso05's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object wrapper and access them that way:

```
var columns = {"column1":"", "column2":"", "column3":""};

for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
    columns[("column" + i)] = i;
}
```

> ```
> columns.column1 = 1
> columns.column2 = 2
> columns.column3 = 3
> ```

Comment: I thought that might be the way I had to do it.  Thanks for confirming this.  I just didn't want to re-write a bunch of code to put them in an object if I didn't have to.

Comment: @BrianPowell an alternative if your variables are global is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1920939/4028085

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this in jQuery, you can also use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    newVar = "";
    for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
      newVar += "var column"+i+" = "+i+";";
    }
    $("<script>").html(newVar).appendTo("head");
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect. I already rewrote this using the answer I accepted, but this actually answers my question perfectly as well. Thanks!