# Javascript Function Global Variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables

I want to create some gauges, but my Gauge object remains undefined.

```
var doesntwork;
function create_gauge(name, id,  min,  max,  title,  label) {
  name = new JustGage({
    id: id,
    value: 0,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    donut: false,
    gaugeWidthScale: 0.3,
    counter: true,
    hideInnerShadow: true,
    title: title,
    label: label,
    decimals: 2
  });
}
create_gauge(doesntwork, "g2", 0, 100, "Füllstand", "%");
console.log(doesntwork); //undefined
```

why? can't i pass variables to a function?

Comment: Please, share what is `JustGage` as well

Comment: Primitives are passed by value, and `doesntwork` is `undefined` - a primitive. So if you modify it in the function as `name`, it has no effect on the `doesntwork` variable. Why don't you just return the result from `new JustGage` from the function?

Comment: its a javascript add-on to create gauges. see https://github.com/toorshia/justgage

Comment: Indeed, one cannot pass *references to* variables to functions, you can only pass values. You could try [passing a string name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1920867/1048572) but really you should follow @KarlReid's advice and just use a `return` value.

Comment: @KarlReid: **Everything** is "pass by value". Only because objects are reference-type values doesn't mean they are "pass by reference". "Pass by reference" means this: `var a = {}; var b = a; b = {}; console.log(a === b); /*this is not true in JavaScript*/` . [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling that's good one..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you only pass values, not variable references or pointers.

For that simple example, returning would seem more appropriate.

```
var works;
function create_gauge(id,  min,  max,  title,  label) {
  return new JustGage({
    id: id,
    value: 0,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    donut: false,
    gaugeWidthScale: 0.3,
    counter: true,
    hideInnerShadow: true,
    title: title,
    label: label,
    decimals: 2
  });
}
works = create_gauge("g2", 0, 100, "Füllstand", "%");
console.log(works);
```

---

However, I'm sure this is probably overly simplified. There are "reference types" in JS, so if `works` held an object, you could pass the value of the object reference and have the function populate a property of the object.

```
var works = {};
function create_gauge(obj, id,  min,  max,  title,  label) {
  obj.data = new JustGage({
    id: id,
    value: 0,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    donut: false,
    gaugeWidthScale: 0.3,
    counter: true,
    hideInnerShadow: true,
    title: title,
    label: label,
    decimals: 2
  });
}
create_gauge(works, "g2", 0, 100, "Füllstand", "%");
console.log(works.data);
```