# Dynamic Object Reference in Object.keys(obj)

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, object-literal, template-literals

How can I iterate through an Object.Keys(obj) where the obj might change (and thus need to be a variable that changes)?

```js
const modelBasicSKUs = {
device: {
    "black": "12",
    "platinum": "23"
  },
  keyboard: {
    "black":"12",
    "blue":"23",
    "red":"34",
    "platinum":"45"
  },
  pen: {
    "black":"12",
    "platinum":"44",
    "burgundy":"56",
    "blue":"45"
  }
};

(async () => {
let selectedDevice = "modelBasic";

document.querySelector('#testel').innerHTML = tmpl;
 const tmpl = `
  ${Object.keys(selectedDevice + 'SKUs').map(key => (
    `<div>${key}</div>`
  )).join("")}
`;

  })();
```

```html
<div id="testel"></div>
```

I believe the important part lies in

`${Object.keys(selectedDevice + 'SKUs').map(key => (`

Do I need another template literal to be able to point to the other objects when selectedDevice changes? I am guessing that [selectedDevice + 'SKUs] expression returns a string and thus Object.keys does not detect an object out of a string?

Comment: Has little to do with the Objects. More like how can I access a variable via a string. Be better to have an object and reference it via the object. Otherwise has to be a global variable.

Comment: Don't have variables named `nnnnnnSKUs`; have a master object with keys named `nnnnnnSKUs` and do `masterObjWithSKUKeys[selectedDevice + 'SKUs']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/get-global-variable-dynamically-by-name-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap the objects inside another object, you can access the objects as string keys from the container object. For instance if you make `modelBasicSKUs` a global object, you will be able to access it as `window['modelBasicSKUs']` or `this['modelBasicSKUs ']`:

```js
modelBasicSKUs = {
device: {
    "black": "12",
    "platinum": "23"
  },
  keyboard: {
    "black":"12",
    "blue":"23",
    "red":"34",
    "platinum":"45"
  },
  pen: {
    "black":"12",
    "platinum":"44",
    "burgundy":"56",
    "blue":"45"
  }
};

let endName = 'SKUs';
console.log(Object.keys(this['modelBasic' + endName]));
```