# how to access a defined variable from another variable where the content is the name of the defined variable (java script)

Tags: javascript, razor-pages

```
var q2312="{'hello world'}";var autogenname="q2312";
```

I auto generate a variable called "autogenname" from razor pages where the content refers to the defined variable. e.g. "q2312" refers to the defined variable name q2312. How do i access the var q2312?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get global variable dynamically by name string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/get-global-variable-dynamically-by-name-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access global variables (defined with `var`) via `window`

```js
var q2312="{'hello world'}";
const autogenname="q2312";

console.log(window[autogenname])
```

I don't know your exact use case, but in general I wouldn't recommend doing it over the global space. Instead you could store the variables in an object and then access it via the keys:

```js
const myData = {
 q2312: 'Hello World'
}

const autoGenName="q2312";

console.log(myData[autoGenName])
```