# Combining two variables to get value of another variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to combine the text values of 2 variables then use that to get the value of a 3rd variable and use that in a calculation. I am hoping if I state the (group + type) correctly that it can be done.
With this code:

```
var group = "flowers";
var type = "rose";

var flowersrose = 20;

var result = 0;

result = result + (group + type);

output = [{id: 123, result: result}];
```

I get:

```
id
123
result
0flowersrose
```

I want:

```
id
123
result
20
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `output = [{id: 123, result: flowersrose }];` instead of `output = [{id: 123, result: result}];
`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var group = "flowers"; 
var type = "rose";

var flowersrose = 20;

result = group + type;
console.log(result);

output = [{id: 123, result: window[result]}];
console.log(output);
```

```
flowersrose
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "result": 20
  }
]
```

More information about the `window[result]` part:

[Get global variable dynamically by name string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/get-global-variable-dynamically-by-name-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I'd warn against polluting the global namespace for such trivial purposes.