# Javascript Call Array With Function Parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

The parameter of the function comes with index page. I have a carname array and need to call carname array use the parameter of function. When i use parameter it will be string value and i can't call array.

```
var refresh = 0;

function NavBarClick(carname) {
  for (var i = 0; i < carbrandsarray.length; i++) {
    if (carname === carbrandsarray[i]) {
      document.title = (carbrandsarray[i]);
      refresh += 1;
      var refrestcontrol = refresh + 1;
      document.getElementById("h1-1defaultcontent").innerHTML = mercedesh1content;
      document.getElementById("p1defaultcontent").innerHTML = mercedesp1content;
      document.getElementById("divimage").src = "";
      allcars = [];
      var cararrayname = carname.toLowerCase() + "cars";
      var cararrayfunc = Array.from(cararrayname);
      for (var i = 0; i < cararrayfunc.length; i++) {
        document.write(cararrayfunc[i] + "<br>");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the definition & initialisation of `carbrandsarray` in your code snippet? And can you add the functions that it references?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/get-global-variable-dynamically-by-name-string-in-javascript

Comment: [Don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1048572)