# Fetch Variable from String (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, variables

Suppose I have a few variables:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
vars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] // Values of them stored in a list
```

Now, I have a for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < vars.length; i ++){
    console.log(vars[i]);
}
```

Here, the output would be `a,b,c,d` but what I'm willing to get is `1,2,3,4`.

*Note: The `vars` list should remain the same. This is just an example of what I'm trying to do...*

Any idea on how we could fetch the variable just by a string name *(given that the string name is exactly the same as the variable name)*?

Comment: Duplicate [Get global variable dynamically by name string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/get-global-variable-dynamically-by-name-string-in-javascript)

Comment: What problem would this solve for you?

Comment: Also your variables should be **declared** with `let`, `const`, or (if really necessary) `var`.

Comment: Also, see ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](/q/5187530/4642212). In practice, you never need — or _want_, really — dynamic variable names. Use a simple object instead: `const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };` … `console.log(obj[vars[i]]);`.

Comment: I simply stated a normal example and I am aware of variable declaration. I don't want the list to be changed simply.

Comment: @Pointy I would like to fetch the user page and based upon that I have variables which I would like to run in a function (without if conditions).

Comment: The idiomatic JavaScript approach would be to have an object contain properties, which can be accessed by a name that's computed somehow, like `object["a"]`.

Comment: @Pointy it won't work in my case since I'll also end up with `undefined` or null strings.

Comment: Well how would you expect things to work with `undefined` or `null` strings if you were gaining access to plain variables somehow?

Comment: That's why I added a one-timer if condition.

Comment: I was trying to fetch the page user is on for animation purposes, I've done it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you're working in a browser.

Since a, b, c, and d are global variables, you can get them from the `window` object:

```js
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
vars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] // Values of them stored in a list

for (i = 0; i < vars.length; i ++){
    console.log(window[vars[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Assuming a browser environment.