# Equivalent of window["myString"] for Local Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

Let say I got a string with the name of the variable I want to create.

If I want to create it with a global scope, I'd use `window["myString"] = 100;` or `global["myString"] = 100;` on Nodejs.

Is there a way to do the same but create the variable with local scope? (Ex: Inside a function)

EDIT: Note: The goal is to access the variable with its name directly. Ex: `myString`

I already know that I could easily create a object that would have the value as an attribute. Ex: `obj.myString`. But this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not just declare it a variable with `var` if you want it inside a local scope? eg: `var x = {}; x.myString = 100;`

Comment: Create an object, put properties on it, access the object's properties dynamically, profit!

Comment: Here's another co-duplicate of that master duplicate question: [Get access to local variable or variable in closure by its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336508/javascript-get-access-to-local-variable-or-variable-in-closure-by-its-name)

Answer (score 0):

The local scope is not exposed as the global object is.

However...

```
function someFunction() {
    var locals = {};

    locals['someLocalVar'] = 'local var';
}
```