# Way to check a bunch of parameters if they are set or not in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

So, this happens to me quite frequently, but here's my latest one:

```
  var generic_error = function(title,msg){
        if(!title){ title= 'Oops!'; }
        if(!msg) { msg = 'Something must have gone wrong, but no worries we\'re working on it!'; }
        $.fancybox(
        {
            content:'\
                <div class="error_alert">\
                    <h2>'+title+'</h2>\
                    <p>'+msg+'\
                </div>'
        });
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way to check all params like `title` and `msg` above and OR set them as optional OR  define defaults in the function like how PHP does it for example? Sometimes i could have 10 options and `if(!var){var='defaults'}` x 10 is icky...

Answer (score 4):

Slightly shorter but equivalent to what you're doing now is to use "||" AKA "or" AKA "the default operator".

```
title = title || 'Oops!';
 msg = msg || 'Something must have gone wrong, but no worries we\'re working on it!';
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll find anything considerably shorter and simpler than `if(!title)title='DefaultTitle'` for function arguments.

However, I'd even use the longer form to make it more explicit: `if (title===null) title='DefaultTitle'`.

Here is a related question with an answer, but I think it would just makes your code more complicated. [How can I access local scope dynamically in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598878/how-can-i-access-local-scope-dynamically-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could use ternary notation as [recommended by this article](http://web-graphics.com/mtarchive/001709.php) but in a simpler form:

```
var n = null;
!title ? title = 'Oops' : n;
```

You've also got the `arguments[]` array which holds the arguments and could be used in a loop, something like this:

```
function test(one,two,three) {
  i=0;
  while(typeof(arguments[i]) != 'undefined') {
    alert(arguments[i++]);
  }
}

test(40,27,399);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (arguments.length) {
  case 0: title = 'Oops';
  case 1: message = 'Something must have gone wrong...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. The argsOK function is a little complex, but calling it is easy.

```
//-----------------------------------------------------
/*
PURPOSE Ensures a function received all required arguments, no extra 
        arguments & (if so specified) no arguments are empty.
RETURNS True if the arguments validate, else false.
*/
function argsOk(
    functionCallee  ,   // Caller's callee object
    allArgsRequired ,   // True = All arguments are required
    emptyArgsAllowed    // True = Empty arguments are allowed
){
    var ok = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
        var functionName = functionCallee.toString().split(' ')[1].split('(')[0];
        var args = functionCallee.arguments;
        var expectedArgCount = functionCallee.length;
        var actualArgCount  = args.length;
        if ((allArgsRequired && actualArgCount < expectedArgCount) ||
            (actualArgCount > expectedArgCount)) {
            error("Function " + functionName + " expected " + expectedArgCount + " arguments, but received " + actualArgCount + ".");
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
        if (emptyArgsAllowed) {
            break;
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < args.length; ++j) {
            if (args[j] != null && args[j].length == 0) {
                error("Function " + functionName + "() received an empty argument.");
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ok;
}
```

Example of calling it (a one-liner, as you can see):

```
//------------------------------------------------
function image(item, name, better)
// PURPOSE Write a request for picture or photo
// ENTRY        Init() has been called
{
    if (!showingShortVersion()) {
        var betterString = '';
        if (better != null && better == true)
            betterString = 'better ';
        if (argsOk(arguments.callee, true, false))
            write('<p class="request maintain">If you have ac&shy;cess to a ' + betterString + item + ' of ' + name + ' that we could put on&shy;line, please <a href="misc/pics.htm" onmouseover="return stat(\'Learn how to send us images\')" onmouseout="return erase()">click here</a>.</p>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, especially in Javascript, clean != short.

Do not use `if(!title){ title= 'Oops!'; }` as a *general* solution, because e.g. `0` and empty string are falsy, too. Arguments that are not set, are `undefined`, so I prefer using

```
if (title === undefined) {
    title= 'Oops!'; 
}
```

It may be more wordy to do so, but It will prevent unwanted side effects, and in my experience, Javascript generates a lot of unwanted side effects, if you try to use shortcuts.