# How to implement a string formatter with variable names

Tags: javascript, formatting, string-formatting

I'd like to implement a string formatter. I've used formatters that take string like `"the quick, brown {0} jumps over the lazy {1}"` where you pass in parameters whose cardinal location is used to replace the braced integers.
I'd love to be able to do something more like `"the quick, brown {animal1} jumps over the lazy {animal2}"` where animal1 and animal2 are variables and are simply evaluated. I got the following method implemented, but then realized that eval is not going to work because it doesn't use the same scope.

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    reg = new RegExp("{([^{}]+)}", "g");
    var m;
    var s = this;
    while ((m = reg.exec(s)) !== null) {
        s = s.replace(m[0], eval(m[1]));
    }
    return s;
};
```

1. Is there a way to do this without using eval (doesn't seem like it).
2. Is there a way to give eval the closure so it gets scope? I tried
   `with(window)` and `window.eval()`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a usage like `var result = "This will get formatted with my {name} and {number}".format({name: "TetsujinOni", number: 1234});`

Why not head off in this direction:

```
String.prototype.format = function(scope) {
    reg = new RegExp("{([^{}]+)}", "g");
    var m;
    var s = this;
    while ((m = reg.exec(s)) !== null) {
        s = s.replace(m[0], scope[m[1]]);
    }
    return s;
};
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution. Thanks, @Tetsujin!

Answer (score 5):

All global variables are defined in the `window` object, so you should be able to do this without eval:

```
String.prototype.format = function(scope) {
    scope = scope || window; //if no scope is defined, go with window
    reg = new RegExp("{([^{}]+)}", "g");
    var m;
    var s = this;
    while ((m = reg.exec(s)) !== null) {
        s = s.replace(m[0], scope[m[1]]);
        //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    return s;
};
```

Here you should also simply be able to change `window` to what scope you feel like.

If variables are **not** in the global scope, but rather in your current scope, you [might want to read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598878/how-can-i-access-local-scope-dynamically-in-javascript) or go with [Tetsujin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19254521/247893).

Comment: Thanks. That's cool. What if my variables are not in global scope? What if they're in a function? `function() { var animal1 = 'fox'; "the {animal1} jumps...".format(); }`

Comment: @JeremyFoster Check my edit - I've added a link to another SO thread refering to this exact problem. Short answer is that you can't *per se* unless you use an internal private object. That said, you could, as Tetsujin's solution refers to, simply parse `this` for his `scope` variable when formatting and you *should* refer to the current scope.

Comment: @JeremyFoster I've edited my post to include a scope object that you can pass as an argument if it's **not** in `window`.

Comment: I think I like it. Let me play.

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes... the holy grail of javascript variable interpolation... You actually *can* pass the local scope around by using dark magic like this:

```
String.prototype.format = function(_eval) {
    return this.replace(/{(.+?)}/g, function($0, $1) {
        return _eval($1);
    })
};

function foo() {
    var a = 123, b = 456;
    s = "a is {a} and a+b={a+b}".format(function(x) {return eval(x)})
    console.log(s) // a is 123 and a+b=579
}
```

I'm afraid there's no way to make the `format` call less verbose.

And here's a version that requires explicit scope passing, but still allows for arbitrary expressions in `{...}`'s:

```
String.prototype.format2 = function(scope) {
    eval(Object.keys(scope).map(
        function(x) { return "var " + x + "=scope." + x
    }).join(";"));
    return this.replace(/{(.+?)}/g, function($0, $1) {
        return eval($1);
    })
};

function foo() {
    var a = 123, b = 456;
    s = "a is {a} and a+b={a+b}".format2({a:a, b:b})
    console.log(s) // a is 123 and a+b=579
}
```

You are not expected to understand this.

Comment: Could said black magic simply be changed to a real function instead of an anonymous one? (`.format(_blackMagic)` or another short function name?)

Comment: That's some pretty black technique, georg.