# Amazon DynamoDB DocumentClient().get() use values outside of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit

How can I get `data.Item.Name` outside of `docClient.get()` to further use it in other functions.

```
const docClient = new awsSDK.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

docClient.get(dynamoParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("failed", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully read data", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        console.log("data.Item.Name: " + data.Item.Name);
    }   
});

// how can i use "data.Item.Name" here:

console.log(data.Item.Name);
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(data.Item.Name)
    .getResponse();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access local scope dynamically in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598878/how-can-i-access-local-scope-dynamically-in-javascript)

Comment: was my answer helpful? @NicolasD

Comment: i am new to dynamo db client. could you please post how you resolve this issue? not able to understand from the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to asynchronous javascript.

Your options are to either:

- continue your logic inside the callback
- refactor your code to use async/await

I will give an example for the async/await option, however you will need some refactoring in other areas of your code, to support this.

```
async function wrapper() {
  const docClient = new awsSDK.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  docClient = require('util').promisify(docClient)

  var data = await docClient(dynamoParams);

  console.log(data.Item.Name);
  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(data.Item.Name)
      .getResponse();
}
```

I assumed that your code lies in a function named `wrapper`. Note that you need to add the `async` keyword to this function.

It also returns a promise now, so to get the return value from `wrapper` you need to `await` it (in the part of the code where you're calling it). Which means that you need to add the `async` keyword to the top level function as well...and so on.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. At the time I asked the question, I was unaware of async in javascript. Your answer would have definitely helped me back then. Thank you for clarification anyways!

Comment: Now you can just do `var result = await docClient.get(dynamoParams).promise()`